# Android send notification using Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

This is my first time to use Parse and first time to develop an Android app. So I have a lot of questions. How can I send notification to specific users using Parse? When wish list item of current user  become available, this user will receive a notification about it. How can I do that?

Comment: Read the parse docs and tutorial https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications